# When did the Server Fault public beta end?

Tags: support

Is [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) out of public beta?

If so, when did it happen? Do you have a reference?

---

[Announcement of start of public beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/server-fault-public-beta-launches/).

Answer (score 2):

Server Fault finished its beta testing on **May 27th, 2009**.

Comment: The private beta ended on that date. What about the public beta?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that the public beta ever ended.

**The term "beta" is only used loosely in this context** as the underlying software was fairly mature at this point -- we had already done a private beta, public beta, and formally removed the literal, encoded-in-the-darn-html "beta" tag on Stack Overflow itself (in Jan 2009 as I recall?)

And since it's essentially the same software..